# Python pandas -> select by condition in columns name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have df with column names: 'a', 'b', 'c' ... 'z'.

```
print(my_df.columns)
Index(['a', 'b', 'c', ... 'y', 'z'],
  dtype='object', name=0)
```

I have function which determine which columns should be displayed. For example:

```
start = con_start()
stop = con_stop()
print(my_df.columns >= start) & (my_df <= stop)
```

My result is:

```
[False False ... False False False False  True  True
True  True False False]
```

My goal is display dataframe only with columns that satisfy my condition.
If start = 'a' and stop = 'b', I want to have:

```
0                                      a              b         
index1       index2                                                  
New York     New York           0.000000       0.000000          
California   Los Angeles   207066.666667  214466.666667     
Illinois     Chicago       138400.000000  143633.333333     
Pennsylvania Philadelphia   53000.000000   53633.333333      
Arizona      Phoenix       111833.333333  114366.666667
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to make this robust and with as few assumptions as possible.

***option 1***
use *`iloc`* with array slicing
**Assumptions:**

- `my_df.columns.is_unique` evaluates to `True`
- columns are already in order

---

```
start = df.columns.get_loc(con_start())
stop = df.columns.get_loc(con_stop())

df.iloc[:, start:stop + 1]
```

***option 2***
use *`loc`* with boolean slicing
**Assumptions:**

- column values are comparable

---

```
start = con_start()
stop = con_stop()

c = df.columns.values
m = (start <= c) & (stop >= c)

df.loc[:, m]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use slicing to achieve this with .loc:

```
 df.loc[:,'a':'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate a list of colums to display:

```
cols = [x for x in my_df.columns if start <= x <= stop]
```

Use only these columns in your DataFrame:

```
my_df[cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming `result` is your `[true/false]` array and that `letters` is `[a...z]`:

```
res=[letters[i] for i,r in enumerate(result) if r]
new_df=df[res]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions are on a similar level of complexity as you shown in your example there is no need to use any additional function but just do filtering e.g.

```
sweet_and_red_fruit = fruit[(fruit[sweet == 1) & (fruit["colour"] == "red")]
print(sweet_and_red_fruit)
```

OR if you want to just print

```
print(fruit[(fruit[sweet == 1) & (fruit["colour"] == "red")])
```